# How can users be redirected from a Firebase cloud notification to a specific filtered result on a page within the iOS and Android apps?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-native-firebase

Using React Native, we have created an iOS and Android app that allows users to book sessions at an indoor workout studio based on the date and time that they want. On occasions, these sessions have unique themes, discounts, and so on, which we want to advertise by sending Firebase notifications. However, because our present redirection simply brings the user to the current date, it is not generating many conversions because the user will have to manually apply filters or identify the date of the specific class.
As a result, we want to make the user flow considerably smoother and be able to send the user directly to a specified (filtered) date/class on clicking upon the notification.

We reached out to Firebase support but they said that since React Native is not supported they cannot provide code help. Hoping we can get some help here!